# Cognos Framework Manager: Create A Variable in Expression Definition

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

Is it possible to create variables in the expression definition of a query item in Framework Manager?

I know I can create another query item and reference that but wondered if this is possible just within the expression itself?

Comment: What do you mean by a variable? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Query Item and use it whenever you like.